# CTRL+C not handled in python script when using su

Tags: python, linux, keyboard-events

I have a Python code like this.

```
try:
    while some_cond_is_still_true:
        ....
except KeyboardInterrupt: # Handle CTRL+C
    ...
```

While the KeyboardInterrupt is handled fine if I run the python script by myself, it is not handled if I run it as another user using `su`, like this.

```
su <some_other_user> -c 'python myprogram.py <args>'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***su*** command creates a new interactive shell and executes the command inside it.
When you use option `-c (--command)` the ***su*** command creates a new session with the user indicated in the command. To solve this use the option `--session-command`.
 In this case the command  will be this:

```
su user_name --session-command 'python myprogram.py <args>'
```

in this case you should be able to catch **CTRL+C interrupt**.

Comment: As far as i know, `--session-command` is not avaliable in every `su` implementation.  Check the `man su` to see if it is avalible for your distribution. `--session-command` works in RedHat, OEL, etc. And: be careful, if you use `--session-command`. This means: only use this option, if you know, what you are doing here!

Comment: Oh yes, right observation! But if available is the cleaner solution.

Comment: If available, is an amazing solution :)

Answer (score 1):

What The Bndr said is true. To solve this problem you can use the signal module to register a new callback function that will be called at SIGTERM signal.
In it you can either raise a KeyboardInterrupt() or set a global variable that controls the program's flow to False.
You can also try registering the default callback again, which does raise the KeyboardInterrupt() exception.

This should make the newly spawned shell propagate the signal correctly. If it doesn't, then you should choose the shell which will launch the script through su, because something is wrong with the one called at this moment. Or check your execute line at the top of your script.
Try playing with it with combinations of calls to the script like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#! /bin/sh python
```

or

```
#! /bin/bash python
```

and so on, and see what works. This assumes your script is made executable and you do not have to call Python interpreter directly. If you plan to distribute your script though, be careful what you leave there. Different distributions will react differently and some even may not have the problem you are currently experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you  use `su <user> -c ...` so an other shell in the conext of the specified user will be established.

I think: if you hit `CTRL+C` it depends on the shell, if the interrupt signal will reach the python scripts.

Try `su <user> -c 'watch ls'` to see, if  `CTRL + C` will stop watching ls.

Not sure, what you trying to do with your script, but if you "only" like to abort an running script, you can do the following (alternatively to `CTRL + C`):

Stop this process (the users shell process) by pressing `CRTL + Z`. The Job number and the stopped process is displayed.
Now you can kill the process using the job number, like `kill %1`